# How to add references with C#

Tags: c#

I want to compile and execute a C# program that needs external dll. In Visual Studio we just add...reference. What is the corresponding way to do that with Ubuntu 16.04? I use the [SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu) from Microsoft.

Comment: what editor are you using?

Comment: @George gedit.... I found a way to do it with mono: `$ mcs -r:FortnoxAPILibrary.dll Program.cs;./Program.exe`

Comment: Please post as an answer for others, great you figured it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do it with mono: `$ mcs -r:FortnoxAPILibrary.dll Program.cs;./Program.exe`