# How to load dll to C# in mono and run it

Tags: mono, c#, selenium

I have some Selenium test cases which were written in Windows. Now I want to run them in Ubuntu. I found a way to link my C# program and selenium dll using [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/943198/832929) solution, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:   
Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=3.14.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.   
File name: 'WebDriver, Version=3.14.0.0, Culture=neutral,   
PublicKeyToken=null' [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:  
System.IO.FileNotFoundException:  
Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=3.14.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullure=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

C#:

```cs
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace SelTest {
    class TestOne {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Command used for compiling and running:

```
mcs -r:/home/local/prasanth/test/dist/lib/net45/WebDriver.dll SelTest.cs; ./SelTest.exe
```

My mono version: 6.6.0.161

The selenium library was downloaded from [here](https://selenium.dev/downloads/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is finally solved by setting the MONO_PATH environmental variable in my .bashrc file.

The [documentation](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/assemblies-and-the-gac/) says:

> At run time, Mono looks in three places for assemblies necessary to
>   run a program. It first searches the location of the executing
>   assembly. If your application uses assemblies not provided by the
>   runtime, you may place them all in the same directory so that Mono may
>   find them. If a required assembly isn’t found there, Mono searches the
>   MONO_PATH environment variable.

In my .bashrc: `export MONO_PATH=/home/local/prasanth/test/dist/lib/net45/`

I added this line and [compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518150/9368703) my .bashrc file. Now my application runs without any problem.